# How to find out if WinJS.Promise was cancelled by timeout or cancel() call

Tags: javascript, promise, winjs, cancellation

I have a server request that is wrapped in a timeout promise.

`var pendingRequest = WinJS.Promise.timeout(5000, requestAsync)`.

The user also has a "Cancel" button on the UI to actively cancel the request by executing `pendingRequest.cancel()`. However, there is no way to find out that the promise has been cancelled by the user or by the timeout (since timeout calls `promise.cancel()` internally too).

It would have been nice of WinJS.Promise.timeout would move the promise in the error state with a different `Error` object like "Timeout" instead of "Canceled".

Any idea how to find out if the request has been cancelled by the timeout?

**Update**: How about this solution:

```
(function (P) {
        var oldTimeout = P.timeout
        P.timeout = function (t, promise) {
            var timeoutPromise = oldTimeout(t);
            if (promise) {
                return new WinJS.Promise(function (c, e, p) {
                    promise.then(c,e,p);
                    timeoutPromise.then(function () {
                        e(new WinJS.ErrorFromName("Timeout", "Timeout reached after " + t + "ms"));
                    });
                });
            } else {
                return timeoutPromise;
            }
        };
    })(WinJS.Promise);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211667.aspx),

> ... the promise enters the error state with a value of Error("Canceled")

Thus, `error.message === 'Canceled'` can be detected in your error handler.

In addition, `WinJS.Promise` allows an `onCancel` callback to be specified at construction time.

```
var promise = new WinJS.Promise(init, onCancel);
```

where `init` and `onCancel` are both functions.

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6zvgpeqw/).

**Edit**

Ah OK, sorry I misread the question. I understand now that you wish to distinguish between a timeout and a manually canceled promise.

Yes, it can be done, by making an appropriate message available to both :

- a WinJS promise's `onCancel` callback
- a chained "catch" callback.

First, extend WinJS.Promise.prototype with a .timeout() method :

```
(function(P) {
    P.prototype.timeout = function (t) {
        var promise = this;
        promise.message = 'Canceled';
        P.timeout(t).then(function() {
            promise.message = 'Timeout';
            promise.cancel();
        });
        return promise.then(null, function() {
            if(error.message == 'Canceled') {
                throw new Error(promise.message); //This allows a chained "catch" to see "Canceled" or "Timeout" as its e.message.
            } else {
                throw error; //This allows a chained "catch" to see a naturally occurring message as its e.message.
            }
        });
    };
})(WinJS.Promise);
```

This becomes a method of each instance of WinJS.Promise(), therefore does not conflict with the static method `WinJS.Promise.timeout()` .

Now, use the `.timeout()` method as follows :

```
function init() {
    //whatever ...
}

function onCancel() {
    console.log('onCacnel handler: ' + this.message || `Canceled`);
}

var promise = new WinJS.Promise(init, onCancel);

promise.timeout(3000).then(null, function(error) {
    console.log('chained catch handler: ' + error.message);
});

promise.cancel();
/* 
 * With `promise.cancel()` uncommented, `this.message` and `error.message` will be "Canceled".
 * With `promise.cancel()` commented out, `this.message` and `error.message` will be "Timeout".
 */
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sf4pxc6n/) (with extra code for button animation).

Comment: I know that. That is __the__ problem. Whether the promise was canceled by `timeout` or by call to `cancel` by someone else than the timeout promise, is not possible to know.

Comment: @philk just... roll your own `.timeout`?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 thanks for this version! I have [refined](http://jsfiddle.net/sf4pxc6n/4/) it a bit. Now it supports proper error chaining and also normal completion of the promise. Also, the timeout-promise is now cancelled when the actual promise completes (with success or error). What do you think?

Comment: (1) I don't think `.wrapError()` is necessary. WinJS promises are throw-safe. If they weren't, my demo would not convey the thrown errors down the error path. (2) It does no harm to cancel the timeout-promise (in two places) but it's not necessary as `promise.cancel()` will do nothing if `promise` has already settled by whatever means. Once settled, a promise's state is immutable.

Comment: (3) You spotted the worst aspect of my version - namely that a rejection for any other reason (neither timeout nor manual cancellation) would be expressed as "Cancelled". My amendment is slightly different from yours (see edited answer).

Comment: (4) Another shortcoming of my version is that `promise.timeout()` instantly decorates the promise with `promise.message = 'Canceled'`. Hence, `promise.message` is only relevant in the `onCancel()` callback. Your version overcomes that but at the cost of not making `promise.message` ("Cancelled" or "Timeout") available in the `onCancel()` callback. The only simple solution I can see would be to stick with my approach but change `promise.message` to `promise.cancelMessage` to make the property less likely understood to be `promise.state`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I do not need the "message" in the `onCancel` callback. The `onCancel` callback does not need to know why it was cancelled. The sample is superficial anyway, since I am using this construct not with my own `Promise` but with async WinRT functions like `HttpClient.sendRequestAsync`. And then I only need to know if the async call timedout or was cancelled by the user.

Comment: As for (1): The WinJS team [recommends](https://github.com/winjs/winjs/issues/504) to use wrapError instead of throw.
(2) I know a second call to `.cancel()` might do nothing and could be only done if the timeout promise was not cancelled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75381/discussion-between-philk-and-roamer-1888).